# glutStrokeString and shaders - all characters on top of each other

Tags: opengl, text, shader

I have a very simple shader that applies a straigthforward WVP transform. It works fine with some geometry, but if I draw a string with glutStrokeString then all characters are drawn one on top of each other.

Is it possible to draw strings with a custom shader, and if so how does the translation of a single character in the string get captured by the shader?

Here are my shaders:
    static const char* pVS = "                                                          \n\
    #version 330                                                                        \n\
    \n\
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;                                             \n\
    \n\
    uniform mat4 Projection;                                                            \n\
    uniform mat4 View;
    \n\
    uniform mat4 World;
    \n\
    \n\
    out vec4 Color;                                                                     \n\
    \n\
    void main()                                                                         \n\
    {                                                                                   \n\
    gl_Position = Projection * View * World * vec4(Position, 1.0);
    \n\
    Color = vec4(clamp(Position, 0, 1), 1.0);
    \n\
    }";

```
static const char* pFS = "                                                          \n\
#version 330                                                                        \n\
\n\
in vec4 Color;                                                                      \n\
\n\
out vec4 FragColor;                                                                 \n\
\n\
void main()                                                                         \n\
{                                                                                   \n\
FragColor = Color;                                                              \n\
}";
```

And here is the draw code:
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_shader, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&camera_projection);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_shader, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&camera_transform);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(world_shader, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&world_transform);

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

unsigned char s[] = "test";
world_transform = scale(mat4(1), vec3(1.0f / glutStrokeLength(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, s)));
glUniformMatrix4fv(world_shader, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&world_transform);
glutStrokeString(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, s);

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is: `glutStrokeString` and shaders don't mix.

The long version is, that `glutStrokeString` uses `glTranslatef`, a fixed function pipeline function, to advance to the next character position. Of course with a purely shader based pipeline, that doesn't use compatibility built-in variables and deprecated fixed function pipeline matrices this doesn't work.

Your best bet would be to reimplement `glutStrokeString` using `glutStrokeCharacter` and apply the character position advancement yourself using `glutStrokeWidth`.